# In KDE, how to enforce window rules on already open windows?

Tags: linux-mint, kde, kde4, kwin

I can set window rules for specific applications and match on process name, window title, window class and more properties.

I want to enforce the rule to a **window name** of a website opened in chrome.

The actual problem is that KDE only looks for the window properties when

- the window is being opened (**initialized**) or
- I change the rules and press "apply"

Of course the overridden properties are set to `force` and not `on initialization`.

Is there a way to *enforce the rules*, as soon as the window title got changed? Multiple seconds are absolutely acceptable.

Thanks for any hints or solutions!

Comment: As I posted here..  there is a complex way to run a KWin script by CLI. I'm still trying to figure out how that script would apply a window rule. MinimizeAll which is a KWin script and even restarting Plasma doesnt seem to do it. But maybe?? there is a way with a KWin script that interacts with the rules somehow. https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=111&t=174630&p=454296#p454296